# How to bring the Virtual numeric keyboard on touch screen devices for textbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am newbie to asp.net mvc. In my web application have a login page that takes id and Pwd as inputs. Issue is that when the user clicks on id text box on touch screen devices(mobile or tablet) that should bring the numeric key board alone. but now it actually it brings the virtual keyboard with alphabets and numbers too. So how can i get the numeric keyboard alone in this scenario.

I have tried the type="number" in html text box control but couldnt work.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9.]*">
```

Or

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>
```

Or

```
<input type="tel"/>
```

Try To apply pattern after `type="number"`

Comment: still it brings the full virtual keyboard @urvasibhatt

Comment: please post your HTML Code so i will help you more

Comment: Add Your .cshtml code in your question...without code i can't able to help you